# SwiftValidator cannot invoke 'validate' with an argument list of type

Tags: swift

I'm using SwiftValidator for form validation and getting following error on validate function

> **error**: cannot invoke 'validate' with an argument list of type
>   '(signup)'

"signup" is my UIView

```
@IBDesignable class signup: UIView {}
```

Comment: show some more code...

Comment: What does the definition of `validate` look like?